# are these steps correct? (complex numbers)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let S be the set of all complex numbers z satisfying |z^2 + z + 1| = 1. Then which of the following statements is/are TRUE?

(A)  |z + 1/2 | ≤ 1/2 for all z ∈ S

B) |z| ≤ 2 for all z ∈ S

(C) |z + 1/2 | ≥ 1/2 for all z ∈ S

(D) The set S has exactly four elements

correct answer are (B)and(C) and I got (C) using my method but following the same method I am getting (B) wrong.

Can someone explain where I went wrong in this solution:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did right. The fact is that you got $|z|\geq 0$ and this information is not sufficient to say that (B) is incorrect.
So you can argue like this:

$1=|z^2+z+1|\geq |z^2+z|-1$, hence $|z^2+z|\leq 2$. Then $|z|^2 -|z|-2 \leq 0$ and this implies that $-1\leq |z| \leq 2$ and hence (B) is correct.
You can actually say that
$0\leq |z| \leq 2$.